# event listener for phantomjs stdin

Tags: javascript, stdin, phantomjs

Is it possible to set up an event listen for phantomjs's `system.stdin` events?

example where phantomjs can read from stdin but halts everything while waiting for input:

```
var system = require('system');

system.stdout.writeLine('waiting for user input...');
var input = system.stdin.readLine();
// anything down here won't execute until input has been received
```

The ideal solution would be like nodejs's [`process.stdin.on()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin)

phantomjs does not seem to give any methods to do this but it must still be possible.

I was thinking I could use [`fs.open()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/open.html) and poll the stream for changes but I can't figure out how to open the right file for stdio/tty or if that's even relevant to what I'm trying to do.

I'm using phantomjs version 1.9.0 on Debian 6

Comment: I've posted the request here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11319

Comment: FWIW I didn't spend too long trying to figure this out. I used a web server to communicate with phantomjs which actually solved my needs better than stdio would have.

Comment: Three years later, this feature request for phantomjs is still open here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11319

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it or even if it is great performance-wise, however it worked fine with the exception that a first STDIN request must be made for the program so it initialises.

#### test.js

```
console.log('initialising program, waiting for user input');

var stdin = require('fs').open('/dev/stdin', 'r');

setInterval(function () {
    var line = stdin.readLine();
    if (line) { console.log('>>', line); }
}, 100);

console.log('logic running async');
```

then you can create a FIFO pipe and attach it to the process

```
$ mkfifo PIPE
$ phantomjs test.js < PIPE
```

and from there on another terminal window you could:

```
echo hello world > PIPE
```

the ouput would be:

```
initialising program
logic running async
>> hello world
```

I don't think this is going to work on windows machines. and again, this might be really bad performance-wise since it uses a defined interval to catch user's input, but if I want to debug a program it is a quick and easy way to do so, by evaluate the input from there.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [issue](http://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11319), the feature is currently not available.

Despite stdin probably being a faster alternative, I went with the webserver method instead.